# "ModuleNotFoundError" error while importing module in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I am getting `"ModuleNotFoundError"` while trying to run a script in python. Below is the directory structure:

```
housekeeping  ---> root folder
      -> src
           ->core1
                ->abc.py  ----> this script has class "xyz"
                -> __init__.py
              
           ->core2
               -> def.py
               -> __init__.py
```

def.py:

```py
from core1.abc import xyz
print("name")
```

when I am calling `def.py`  as part of startup.sh which is used to create docker image as below:

```
**/housekeeping/venv/bin/python3.7 /housekeeping/src/core2/def.py**
```

Its giving `*module not found error*` for `folder1` even though I have included `__init__.py` file.

I replaced `folder1.abc import xyz` with `src/folder1.abc import xyz` and adding `__init__.py` for `src` folder, then also getting same error.

Comment: You have to dynamically add "<path_to>/sys" to sys.path. Or you can run a script in src that imports and runs def so that 'src' is automatically in sys.path from the start.

Comment: @Harvey thanks for response . can you elaborate more on this

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the path to the `src` directory to `sys.path` in order for `def` to be able to "see" `core1`. The path to `src` can be added dynamically or a script in `src` can import and run `def`. The current directory of the executed script is always added to the path.

Try the following code as an example. Try running src.py, core2.py, and def.py. I've included the output of them on my machine below.

```
hchapman@ONI-J77SRN2 MINGW64 ~/TT/src
$ ls -R
.:
core1/  core2/  src.py

./core1:
core1.py

./core2:
core2.py  def.py

hchapman@ONI-J77SRN2 MINGW64 ~/TT/src
$ head src.py core1/core1.py core2/core2.py core2/def.py
==> src.py <==
print('src')

import sys
print(sys.path[0])

import core2.core2


==> core1/core1.py <==
print('core1')


==> core2/core2.py <==
print('core2')

import sys
print(sys.path[0])

import core1.core1


==> core2/def.py <==
print('def')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from os import path
    import sys
    sys.path.append(path.abspath(path.join(path.dirname(__file__), path.pardir)))

    import core2

hchapman@ONI-J77SRN2 MINGW64 ~/TT/src
$ python src.py
src
C:\Users\hchapman\TT\src
core2
C:\Users\hchapman\TT\src
core1

hchapman@ONI-J77SRN2 MINGW64 ~/TT/src
$ python core2/core2.py
core2
C:\Users\hchapman\TT\src\core2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hchapman\TT\src\core2\core2.py", line 6, in <module>
    import core1.core1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core1'

hchapman@ONI-J77SRN2 MINGW64 ~/TT/src
$ python core2/def.py
def
core2
C:\Users\hchapman\TT\src\core2
core1
```